# Checking for null before ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, string, properties

Here's the scenario...

```
if (entry.Properties["something"].Value != null)
  attribs.something = entry.Properties["something"].Value.ToString();
```

While effective and working correctly, this looks ugly to me.  If I don't check for a null before performing the ToString() then it throws an exception if the property was null.  Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Much appreciated!

Comment: So, what should the output be if the value is null?

Comment: It would use the default value assigned to attribs.something

Comment: @dscoduc I'm looking for your HTA jQuery info from 2009.  Is that still around?  Your blog and site seem to be offline.

Comment: **see also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do ToString for a possibly null object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987618/how-to-do-tostring-for-a-possibly-null-object)

Comment: My question was from 2009 and the one you referenced is from 2010... so the other is a duplicate of mine, no?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Update 8 years later (wow!) to cover [c# 6's null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
var value = maybeNull?.ToString() ?? String.Empty;
```

Other approaches:

```
object defaultValue = "default";
attribs.something = (entry.Properties["something"].Value ?? defaultValue).ToString()
```

I've also used this, which isn't terribly clever but convenient:

```
public static string ToSafeString(this object obj)
{
    return (obj ?? string.Empty).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Do you know off hand if the "default" could be replaced with string.Empty?

Comment: +1 and Answer:  Just tested it and worked perfectly...  Thank you!

Comment: Note that if the method making the call runs more than once and attribs is reused then you may be overwriting valid data gotten on 1 call with 'default' on a subsequent call.

Comment: @xcud: True. In that case, he should use the following code:    attribs.something = (entry.Properties["something"].Value ?? (objcet)attribs.something).ToString();

Answer (score 42):

If you are targeting the .NET Framework 3.5, the most elegant solution would be an extension method in my opinion.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string NullSafeToString(this object obj)
    {
        return obj != null ? obj.ToString() : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
attribs.something = entry.Properties["something"].Value.NullSafeToString();
```

Comment: Beautiful. I'm just facing a conversion from 1.1 to 4.0, and in 1.1, null.ToString() actually returned "", so I got a couple of thousand occurrences to check for null-safety now. If I get this to work, this will make the transition so much smoother!

Answer (score 39):

```
Convert.ToString(entry.Properties["something"].Value);
```

Comment: 40-Love - no, this returns null not an empty string if value is null.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock no, check the documentation: the returned value of Convert.ToString(object value) is "The String representation of the value of 'value', or String.Empty if value is a null". A quick check in an actual program confirms this.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an empty string to an object is a common idiom that lets you do null-safe `ToString` conversion, like this:

```
attribs.something = ""+entry.Properties["something"].Value;
```

When `entry.Properties["something"].Value` is `null`, this quietly returns an empty `string`.

**Edit:** Starting with C# 6 you can use `?.` operator to avoid `null` checking in an even simpler way:

```
attribs.something = entry.Properties["something"].Value?.ToString();
//                                                     ^^
```

Comment: this is more terse than the weird Convert.ToString call.

Comment: @thepaulpage There's an even better way in C# 6.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not do:

```
attribs.something = entry.Properties["something"].Value as string;
```

Comment: No, you can't; if it's 'null' you'll get a null reference error.

Comment: that works since it returns null string if value is null, and it does not throw exception.

Comment: This does not work for value types. 'string str = myFloat as string;' fails. You will get the following compiler error _Cannot convert type 'float' to 'string' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion_

Comment: Nooooo, if the type is not string will return null always!!! this is casting and not conversion! and won't work form value types!

Answer (score 2):

```
attribs.something = String.Format("{0}", entry.Properties["something"].Value);
```

Not sure about performance though...

Answer (score 2):

In C# 6.0 you can do it in a very elegant way:

`attribs.something = entry.Properties["something"].Value?.ToString();`

And here is an article about new [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As a variation to RexM's answer:

```
attribs.something = (entry.Properties["something"].Value ?? attribs.something).ToString()
```

The only downside would be that the attribs.something would be assigned a value (itself, in this example) even if entry.Properties["something"].Value was null - which could be expensive if the .something property did some other processing and/or this line executes a lot (like in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

To do precisely what you're trying to do a helper method can always be used:

```
CopyIfNotNull(entry.Properties["something"].Value, out attribs.something);

void CopyIfNotNull(string src, out string dest)
{
  if(src != null)
    dest = src;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify "out" in the second argument of the CopyIfNotNull?

Comment: yup. I realized that after I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
attribs.something  = string.Format("{0}",entry.Properties["something"].Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it somehow possible to do something like 
[Dale Ragan's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550374/checking-for-null-before-tostring/550399#550399), but overriding ToString() instead of creating a new NullSafeToString() method?  I'd like this (or returning "null") to be the default behaviour.  The compiler (Visual C# 2010 Express) doesn't complain when I add the following method to public static class ObjectExtensions, but the method doesn't get called...

```
public static String ToString(this Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else
    {
        return obj.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, since instance methods have higher priority than extension methods

Answer (score 0):

How about using an auxiliary method like this:

```
attribs.something = getString(
    entry.Properties["something"].Value, 
    attribs.something);

static String getString(
    Object obj,
    String defaultString)
{
    if (obj == null) return defaultString;
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `??` operator:

```
attribs.something = 
    (entry.Properties["something"].Value ?? attribs.something).ToString();
```

(note the redundant `ToString()` call when the value is `null`)