# ToString on null string

Tags: c#, string, exception, null, tostring

Why does the second one of these produce an exception while the first one doesn't?

```
string s = null;
MessageBox.Show(s);
MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
```

Updated - the exception I can understand, the puzzling bit (to me) is why the first part doesn't show an exception. This isn't anything to do with the Messagebox, as illustrated below.

Eg :

```
string s = null, msg;
msg = "Message is " + s; //no error
msg = "Message is " + s.ToString(); //error
```

The first part appears to be implicitly converting a null to a blank string.

Comment: The safe way to do- see [How to do ToString for a possibly null object?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3987671)

Comment: To avoid `null` damage on a string or object, `obj?.ToString() ?? ""`

Comment: For second line, the error happens because you invoke a method (.ToString()) on a null string reference. This is why you get an exception.

Answer (score 31):

because you cannot call instance method `ToString()` on a  `null` reference.

And `MessageBox.Show()` is probably implemented to ignore null and print out empty message box.

Comment: First bit is fine, but I think the MessageBox bit of my question is distracting, hence my update.

Answer (score 15):

As this question ranks quite high on Google for a search for "c# toString null", I would like to add that the `Convert.ToString(null)` method would return <strike>an empty</strike> a null string, which is ignored by the messagebox.

However, just to reaffirm the other answers, you can use `string.Concat("string", null)` in this example.

Edit - modified answer in line with HeyJude's comment below. As pointed out, a method like `Convert.ToString(null).Length` will throw an exception.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(null)` returns a null value, not an empty string (this can be verified by calling `Convert.ToString(null) == null`, which returns `true`). However, passing a null *variable* indeed equals to null, so that `object v = null; Convert.ToString(v) == string.Empty` returns true (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053198/3002584)).

Comment: @HeyJude - well spotted, thank you! I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

It is because MessageBox.Show() is implemented with pinvoke, it calls the native Windows MessageBox() function.  Which doesn't mind getting a NULL for the lpText argument.  The C# language has much stricter rules for pure .NET instance methods (like ToString), it always emits code to verify that the object isn't null.  There's some background info on that in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Behind the scenes concat is being called in your follow up question / update E.g

```
string snull = null;

string msg = "hello" + snull;

// is equivalent to the line below and concat handles the null string for you.
string msg = String.Concat("hello", snull);

// second example fails because of the toString on the null object
string msg = String.Concat("hello", snull.ToString());

//String.Format, String.Convert, String.Concat all handle null objects nicely.
```

Comment: Can you show us this *behind the scenes* because I surely can't find it in mscorlib...

Comment: So you mean String utility methods just convert it to 'null' string if value returned is null ?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Use ildasm.exe on compiled sample code, and you will see what James wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry but, this is gold when you have nullable integers. You can write string s = "" + myInt; Thanks, 6 years later !

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute the ToString() method on a null. You need a valid object in order to execute a method.

Answer (score 1):

The .show function must have null checking and handle it.

Comment: As others have said, the exception is raised because a method is called on a null reference.

Comment: Indeed. That is the obvious part.

Answer (score 1):

ToString() can't operate on null reference of s vairable

The shortest way

```
obj?.ToString()
```

Another correct ways

```
obj?.ToString() ?? string.Empty  
obj?.ToString() ?? "default string value"
```

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2421572

Answer (score 0):

Because, the second call is expecting an object of "s" to satisfy a ToString() method request. so, before .Show() is called, the s.ToString() would failed with an attempt to call a method.

Interestingly, While .Show() is implemented correctly, many such  methods expect non null instances to be passed in. Usually, that is when you use a [NullObject](http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/) pattern so that the caller should not have to deal with this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Show method handles a null value and just shows nothing. 
The second use of s - s.ToString() fails because you there is no ToString method to run.

Answer (score 0):

As you say yourself it has nothing to do with `MessageBox`, it depends on the implementation of the `ToString()` method.

For example looking at `struct Nullable<T> where T : struct` from `System.Runtime` that a nullable enum uses as example:

```
[Serializable]
[NonVersionable] // This only applies to field layout
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeForwardedFrom("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
public partial struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

It's implementation of `ToString()` looks like this for .NET 7:

```
public override string? ToString() => hasValue ? value.ToString() : "";
```

Therefore the following code gives an exception on `MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());` even though `ToString()` is called on a null object for `tc.TestEnum`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tc = new TestClass();
        MessageBox.Show(tc.TestEnum.ToString());

        string s = null;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    None = 0
}

public class TestClass
{

    public TestEnum? TestEnum { get; set; }

}
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

[image]

Looking at `class String` from `System.Runtime`:

```
[Serializable]
[NonVersionable] // This only applies to field layout
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeForwardedFrom("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
public sealed partial class String : IComparable, IEnumerable, IConvertible, IEnumerable<char>, IComparable<string?>, IEquatable<string?>, ICloneable
```

Here we have another implementation that will throw the error you see:

```
// Returns this string.
public override string ToString()
{
    return this;
}
```

However starting with `.NET 6<` `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` is enabled by default for new projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

The code above will therefore give you two warnings:

`string s = null;` -> [CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600)#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference)

`MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());` -> [CS8602 Dereference of a possibly null reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8602)#possible-dereference-of-null)

[image]

Rewrite the code like this and the errors disappear:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tc = new TestClass();
        MessageBox.Show(tc.TestEnum.ToString());

        string? s = null;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        if (s is not null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
        }
        
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    None = 0
}

public class TestClass
{

    public TestEnum? TestEnum { get; set; }

}
```

Or simply using the null-conditional operator `?.` like @mr R writes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tc = new TestClass();
        MessageBox.Show(tc.TestEnum.ToString());

        string? s = null;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        MessageBox.Show(s?.ToString());
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    None = 0
}

public class TestClass
{

    public TestEnum? TestEnum { get; set; }

}
```