# Why does .ToString() on a null string cause a null error, when .ToString() works fine on a nullable int with null value?

Tags: c#, string, null, int, nullable

`selectedItem` has two fields:

- `int? _cost`
- `string _serialNumber`

In this example, `_cost` and `_serialNumber` of `selectedItem` are BOTH null. I am reading through the fields of `selectedItem` via their properties, and filling in textboxes with their values, when...

```
TextBox1.Text = selectedItem.Cost.ToString(); //no error
TextBox2.Text = selectedItem.SerialNumber.ToString(); //error
```

I understand that `SerialNumber.ToString()` is redundant (because it is already a string), but I don't understand why this causes this exception:

> Nullable object must have a value.

- `int? _cost` is nullable, and does not have a value, yet it does not give me the exception.
- `string _serialNumber` is nullable, and does not have a value, yet it **does** give me the exception.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793601/tostring-on-null-string) touches on it, the guy is essentially asking the same thing, but there is no designated answer, and it also doesn't explain why a nullable `int`? For example, can I use `.ToString()` on a nullable int but not on a null string?

Comment: The question you linked to is not the same at all. That question is about how `MessageBox.Show` and `String.Concat` work with `null` strings.

Comment: Note that you're using the word "nullable" to mean two totally different things. `int?` is a value type, which is called `Nullable<T>`, that has special handling for null values; `string` is a reference type, (though a somewhat odd one) which can *actually have* a value of `null`. An `int?` always has a value, it just has a special way of saying "I'm acting like `null` right now."

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Because `string` type's `null` really points to nothing, there isn't any object in memory.
But `int?` type(nullable) even with value set to `null` still points to some object.
If you read Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" you'll find out that nullable type are just facade classes for common types with some incapsulated logics in order to make work with DB null more convenient.

Check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) to learn about nullable types.

Comment: So basically because it's not actually null, it's just pretending to be?

Comment: Yes, basically it's a structure wrapped around an int field and boolean sign indicating whether this structure was set to int value, or still unitialized, which mean null. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net) topic Mark Gravell pasted implementation on `Nullable<T>` type.

Comment: `int?` or `Int32?`. Not `Int?`

Comment: This is all correct, but also note that `selectedItem.Cost.GetType()` *will* throw if `Cost` is null of type `int?`. The difference is that `ToString` is a virtual method which is overridden by `Nullable<T>` and so can be called on the `int?` directly. On the other hand `GetType` is a non-virtual method declared on a base class of `Nullable<T>` (on `object` in fact). Therefore the runtime will have to convert the `Nullable<>` to that class type before it can call `GetType`, and that is what is called **boxing**, but `Nullable<>` has special boxing rules, so a null reference is produced.

Answer (score 34):

A `Nullable<int>` is a `struct` and can't really be null. So a method call on a "null" struct still works.

There is some "compiler magic" that makes `_cost == null` a valid expression.

Comment: It's compiler magic. Adding an implicit conversion from `null` to `Nullable<T>` using ordinary C# code (i.e. operator overloading) would require that you be able to infer a type from the expression "`null`", which you can't, as it doesn't have one. The compiler essentially turns `Nullable<T> foo = null` into `Nullable<T> foo = default(Nullable<T>)` and `foo == null` into `!foo.HasValue`.

Answer (score 16):

`int?` is not actually an object in its own but it's a `Nullable<int>` object.

So when you declare `int? _Cost`, you are actually declaring `Nullable<int> _Cost` and the property of `_Cost.Value` is `undefined` not the `_Cost` object itself.

> It is actually a syntactic sugar to use `non nullable` types like `int`, `bool` or `decimal` easily.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `System.Nullable<T>`, where `T` is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.

Comment: Technically, `_Cost.Value` is undefined when `_Cost` is null (i.e. when `_Cost.HasValue` is false)

Comment: @AlexBrault: `_Cost` can't really be `null` as it isn't a reference type.

Comment: @comecme: Thus the parenthetical clarification.

Answer (score 4):

The Nullable is actually a struct exposing two properties: HasValue and Value. If you do this you will get your error:

```
int? i = null;
i.Value.ToString()
```

In order to check whether or not your int? has a value you can access `i.HasValue`

Comment: Not _completely_ true. That code will not throw a `NullReferenceException`, but an `InvalidOperationException`. See [Nullable(T).Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

A string is a reference type, but a nullable int is a value type. Here is a Good discussion of the differences http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simple. `int?` or [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) is a *struct* or a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), **it can never be null**.

So what happens when we do:

```
int? _cost = null;
```

`_cost` will have two fields `Value` and `HasValue`, when we assign `null` to `_cost` its  `HasValue` flag will be set to `false` and the `Value` field would be assigned `default(T)` in case of `int?` it would `0`.

Now when we call `ToString` on `_cost`, `Nullable<T>` has an override definition of `ToString`, which if we look at [Microsoft's provided Source Reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#d83d2db767b43db7#references) is implemented like:

```
public override string ToString() {
    return HasValue ? value.ToString() : "";
}
```

Thus it returns an empty string, since `_cost` is assigned `null`.

Now comes the case of `string _serialNumber`. Being `string` it is a reference type and it can *purely* hold `null`. If it is holding `null` then calling `ToString` on it would produce the Null Reference Exception as expected.

You may see: [Value Types and Reference Types - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

what i think the reason is, when the compiler encounters a primitive data type it wraps it, to its corresponding object. The toString() method call is just an indirect call(wrapping and then calling the method) here and the exception is handled there.
While in the case of String, we are directly calling the method. When pointing to a null, the method throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox2.Text = selectedItem.SerialNumber.ToString(); //error
```

yiels error because it's calling function [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tostring.aspx) which is member of **System.String**. This function returns this instance of System.String; no actual conversion is performed. Also, String is a reference type. A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data.

```
TextBox1.Text = selectedItem.Cost.ToString(); //no error
```

yields no error because it's calling to function  [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x70d7t0y) which is a member of **System.Integer**. This function converts the numeric value of this instance to its equivalent string representation. Also, Integer is a value type. A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation.

The same function name ToString() but performs different task.

[String.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tostring.aspx)

[Int32.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x70d7t0y)

[Value types and reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)