# Why does some methods work while some do not on null values of nullable structs?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, nullable

Straight to the point:

```
int? i = null;
i.ToString(); //happy
i.GetType(); //not happy
```

I get a [very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446838/why-does-tostring-on-a-null-string-cause-a-null-error-when-tostring-works) which actually deals on why does `i.ToString()` work fine.

**Edit:** Just found out this corner case has been [the most voted one in this SO thread!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194671/661933)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `ToString` is virtual while `GetType` is not. Nullables have special boxing behavior in the CLR. When you call `GetType` on a nullable it is boxed (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), actually this happens for any `struct`). However, with a nullable, the the underlying value is boxed, not the actual nullable. `ToString` on the other hand calls the override of ToString method on `Nullable<T>`. Also, I would note that `int? i = null` is syntax sugar for `Nullable<int> i = new Nullable<int>()`. So, there really is an object in your variable `i`.

Comment: At first I thought your last sentence is terribly wrong, but not!! That's unbelievable..

Comment: +1. The key is the boxing behavior. I actually sent almost the same question to Jon Skeet because it reminded me of his ".NET brain teasers"

Comment: But I find this as one of the downsides of .NET. The less confusing, the better the language and framework is..

Comment: Another thing is that `GetType` works by examining the type descriptor of a heap object.  The only way that can happen is if it has a heap object it can examine.  Unfortunately, Microsoft decided that `Equals(null, default(int?))` should be true, so `default(int?)` boxes as `null` rather than as an `int?.Empty` value analogous to `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does `i.ToString()` not fail?

Use any .NET decompiler and look at the `Nullable<T>` class. You'll see that `ToString()` is overriden as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  if (!this.HasValue)
    return "";
  else
    return this.value.ToString();
}
```

---

> Why does `i.GetType()` fail?

See [mike z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12886469/390819).

Answer (score 0):

The type `int?` is not a regular type.

When you write `int? i = null`, **only** the value of the object being null, but not the object itself.

The object `int?` inheritance from `object`, so the function `i.ToString()` can work, and it work on the **value** that inside the object.