# Why null statement ToString() returns an empty string?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am just wondering what is the difference between the two next statements:

1. Causes a NullReferenceException - it is OK.

   ```
   object test1 = default(int?);
   object result = test1.ToString();
   ```
2. Returns an empty string "", why?

   ```
   object test2 = default(int?).ToString();
   ```
3. This is same as 2.

   ```
   int? test3 = null;
   if (test3.ToString() == string.Empty) //returns true
   {
       Console.WriteLine("int? = String.Empty, isn't it strange?").
   }
   ```
4. And just for fun - I can prove that bool can be equal to int value (hmmm how? bool can be only false, or true and int never can be that).

   ```
   if (default(int?).ToString() == default(bool?).ToString()) //returns true because both are empty strings
   {
       Console.WriteLine("int = bool");
   }
   ```

*Note:* default(int?) returns null.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is a value-type and can't actually be `null`. It's just programmed in a way so that comparisons with `null` return true if the `HasValue` property is `false`. (And setting it to `null` will set the `HasValue` proeprty to `false`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446838/why-does-tostring-on-a-null-string-cause-a-null-error-when-tostring-works?rq=1

Comment: `object test2 = default(int?).ToString();` is getting translated into `object test2 = ((object)null).ToString();` in **ILSpy** but the second line throws exception. May be its an issue with ILSpy ? otherwise Servy's answer looks perfect.

Comment: For extra fun, try calling `GetType()` on the default(int?) that did not throw an exception while calling `ToString()`.  Boxing can be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An `int?` is a `Nullable<int>`.  `Nullable` is a **struct**, which makes it a value type, not a reference type.  `test3` isn't actually set to `null`.  Assigning `null` to it actually results in the creation of a new structure that simply has the `HasValue` field of that struct set to `false` instead of `true`.  (Special compiler support is required for such an implicit conversion to take place; so you couldn't have your own `MyNullable<T>` type that did this.)

Since the nullable object has an actual value, it can call `ToString` and provide a meaningful value, in this case, an empty string.

When you box that nullable value by putting it in an `object` variable it will result in an *actual* `null` value being stored in that variable, which is why you get a NRE when calling a method on it.

When a nullable value type is boxed it doesn't box the nullable value type; instead if it has no value it assigns `null` to the object, if it has a value then that underlying value is unwrapped and then boxed.  (Special support from the runtime is required for this behavior, which is another reason why you can't make your own `MyNullable<T>` type.)

Answer (score 1):

In C, one uses the token `.` to access a member of the left operand, and `->` to access a member of the thing to which the left operand holds a pointer (reference).  A null reference occurs if the left-hand operand of `->` is null.  In C#, the `.` has the former meaning when applied to value types and the latter meaning when applied to class types; using `.` in C# on a *class type* variable which is null will trigger a `NullReferenceException`.

The .NET type `Nullable<T>` is a two-field structure which contains Boolean field which indicates whether it has a meaningful (non-null) value, and field of value type `T` to say what that value is (if not null).  Although the compiler will allow one to assign a `Nullable<T>` to null or compare one with null, the `null` in the former case is really just shorthand for a default instance (where the "has-value" flag is false, and the value field holds the default value for type T), and the comparison to null is really just a shorthand for checking the `HasValue` property (which in turn looks at the `Boolean` field).  Invoking `ToString` on e.g. a `Nullable<int>` which is "null" is no different semantically from invoking it on any other structure that contains a `Boolean` and an `Int32` which have the values `False` and `0`, respectively.  There are a few ways in which compilers treat nullable types "specially", but a default-valued `Nullable<int>` holds `[False, 0]`, not a null reference.

Note that the first example throws because of one of the "special" rules the framework applies to nullable types.  Casting a value type to `Object` or another reference type generally instructs the runtime to create an object that will behave as a class object with fields and members matching those of the struct and return a reference to that new object--a process known as "boxing".  Because the designers of nullable types wanted to allow code to say `if (NullableThing == null)` rather than the (IMHO sematically clearer) `if (!NullableThing.HasValue)`, the runtime was implemented so that boxing a nullable whose `HasValue` field is false will yield a null reference rather than a reference to a default-valued instance of `Nullable<T>`.  While I think there are cases where would make sense to have some value types use different box and unbox methods, nullable types are the only ones that can use anything other than normal boxing.

Comment: This explanation is correct but incomplete : it doesn't explain why it throws in the first case... and this is because a "null" nullable is boxed to a null reference.