# Displaying a value in my View throws an error with ToString if value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, tostring

In my view in asp.net core, I am trying to display my values in a `@foreach`. Here it is

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.Birthdate.Value.ToString("d")</td>
        <td>@item.Startdate.Value.ToString("d")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This throws a database error when there is a null value in `Startdate`.

If I change `@item.Startdate.Value.ToString("d")` to

`@item.Startdate`,
I do not get the error anymore. All of my properties are nullable.

My confusion is because I thought that if I use `.Value.ToString("whatever")` this would ensure there is a value, if so then it would `ToString()` it, if there is no value then it would leave it null and nothing would happen.

My question is how I can `ToString` a value in my view if its not null, otherwise ignore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .ToString() on a null string cause a null error, when .ToString() works fine on a nullable int with null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446838/why-does-tostring-on-a-null-string-cause-a-null-error-when-tostring-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Nullable has no value (`HasValue` is false) it is an invalid operation to request its `Value`, and if your code uses your nullable's `.Value` directly without checking it first you can probably skip using nullables! :)

The idea behind Nullable is to help deal with a situation of having something that cannot be null, and then needing a way to make it nullable because it's "unavoidable" but you then need to check, for every situation you use it, whether it has a value or not and act appropriately

If you want to have a nullable that might or might not have a value, and you want to blind call something on it and know you have a value, then you need something like:

```
item.Startdate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).ToString("d")
```

You have to make a decision as to what value to use if there is no current value. You can shortcut things by using the null propagator against the nullable:

```
item.Startdate?.ToString("d")
```

If the nullable has no value this whole thing evaluates to `null`. If it has a value, it evaluates to a `DateTime` (or whatever type is in the nullable) that is then `ToString`'d. You can only really use this in contexts that will tolerate null, such as setting a textbox's text

As it evaluates to null it can be null coalesce'd too:

```
item.Startdate?.ToString("d") ?? DateTime.MinValue.ToString("d")
```

The shorter variation of this being to coalesce the nullable datetime with an actual datetime, then tostring the result:

```
(item.Startdate ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToString("d")
```

This last form works like the `GetValueOfDefault` variation earlier, it's just the `??` wasn't a thing until recently; `GVOD()` is much older

Comment: I tried the null propagator and that worked. I did not know that `?` would in my view. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. You can follow the same for Birthdate as well.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var sDate = item.Startdate.HasValue ? item.Startdate.Value.ToString("d") : "";
    <tr>
        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
        <td>@item.LastName</td>
        <td>@item.Birthdate.Value.ToString("d")</td>
        <td>@sDate </td>
    </tr>
}
```