# How to convert null value into string in c# .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using gridview's default update method in which it allows me to update row in gridview itself by converting cells into textboxes.

I want to check validations that if a particular textbox (cell) remains empty or blank then it should not update its value.

For that i have written following code:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues[0].ToString())
```

But it gives an error like object reference not set to an instance of an object. May be it can not convert null value of `e.Newvalues[0]` to **string**.

All answers are appreciated in advance.

Comment: If `e.NewValues[0]` is null, then yes, you are correct - calling `ToString()` on it will fail.  What data type is `e.NewValues[0]`?

Comment: if(e.NewValues[0].Equals(null))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(e.NewValues[0]));
```

A bit of (probably unneeded) explanation:

`Convert.ToString()` will return null for a `(string)null`, and an empty string for an `(object)null` (or any other null).

Either case will give the expected result, because we're checking with `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

In any case, its behaviour is the same as `someValue.ToString()` except it handles the cases where `someValue` is null.

Comment: Did you try that? It will return an empty string.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So? That isn't a problem, since `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will treat `null` and `""` the same way. This is a correct answer.

Comment: Ugh, better get more coffee, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
e.NewValues[0] == null || e.NewValues[0].ToString() == string.Empty
```

If `e.NewValues[0]` is already a string, you could just do this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues[0])
```

**Update** as of C# 6, you could also use:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValues[0]?.ToString())
```

Or even:

```
$"{e.NewValues[0]}" == string.Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code

```
 (e.NewValues[0] == null) ? string.Empty : e.NewValues[0].ToString()
```

The above code will will return the string equivalent if not null, otherwise it will return empty string.

Otherwise you can use following code. This will handle the null case.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString( e.NewValues[0] )
```

Comment: Your first line of code seems to return either a string or a bool so I don't think will compile (or do what is wanted). Did you mean to have the `IsNullOrEmpty` call wrapping the whole thing rather than just in the last expression?

Answer (score 1):

Another (wasteful) way to do it is with a singleton with an overridden `ToString` and `??`  (overkill but it lets me use `??` :P)

```
(e.NewValues[0] ?? Empty._).ToString();
```

The code for the singleton is here:

```
public sealed class Empty
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Empty> lazy =
        new Lazy<Empty>(() => new Empty());
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "";
    }
    public static object _ { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private Empty()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check that e.NewValues[0] isn't null prior to doing a .ToString() on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow row = grd.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     for (int i = 0; i <= row.Cells.Count; i++)
     {
         String str = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[i].Controls[0])).Text;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         { 
          //Your Code goes here ::
         }
     }
}
```