# e.NewValues return Null in Asp.Net DetailsView ItemUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a details view to display user details and update it if necessary. I am using e.NewValues to get the edit state values to update. But it throws a Null Exception. The codes are below.

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="MyDetailsView" CssClass="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="15"
    ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnModeChanging="MyDetailsView_ModeChanging"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" OnItemUpdating="MyDetailsView_ItemUpdating">

    <FieldHeaderStyle CssClass="gvheader" Width="100px" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="#666666" />
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F97BA" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="white" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address" SortExpression="Address">
            <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="450px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Postcode" DataField="Postcode" SortExpression="Postcode">
            <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="450px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country" DataField="Countries" SortExpression="Countries">
            <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="450px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Fields>

    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void MyDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    string address = e.NewValues["Address"].ToString();
    string postcode = e.NewValues["Postcode"].ToString();
    string country = e.NewValues["Countries"].ToString();

    Client c = new Client();
    c.UpdateMyDetails((string)Session["Code"], address, postcode, country); 
    MyDetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly); 
    MyDetailsView.DataBind();

}
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Where do you Bind your Details View?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindMyDetailsView();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe this will help others that come across this problem like I did.

For my solution I used null tertiary
Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["Countries"]) ?? " ";

Here was another post that helped me that had some explanations.
[How to convert null value into string in c# .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053126/how-to-convert-null-value-into-string-in-c-sharp-net)