# Method Returning only " "

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I need return string of DateTime. More this method is returning only null
receives an input string, convert to DateTime and i need put DateTime on valor.retorna_date_time string variable.

Code:

```
   public void Search_DATE(string param_date)
    {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        vsql = "SELECT [IDCADASTRO],[RGP],[PEIXE],[PESO],[QUANTIDADE],[DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE DATA_REGISTRO LIKE @DATA_REGISTRO";

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dtParam = DateTime.Parse(param_date);

                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", dtParam));
                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objReader.Read())
                {

                    valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetString(6);

                }

            }
            catch (SqlException erro)
            {
                throw erro;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }


        }


    }
```

Input Parameters:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string DateTimesql = myDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

objSQL.Search_DATE(DateTimesql);
```

valor.retorna_date_time is a global string variable.

Comment: how many items are expecting to be returned?

Comment: I need return only [DATA_REGISTRO].

Comment: You should also not `throw erro;` but instead just `throw;` inside the `catch` block. This preserves the entire stack trace and exception details.

Comment: Ok. Any tip for my problem ?

Comment: What's your table look like? It's odd to me your parameter name is the same as your column name.

Answer (score 4):

Your `SELECT` statement returns 6 columns:

```
[IDCADASTRO],[RGP],[PEIXE],[PESO],[QUANTIDADE],[DATA_REGISTRO]
```

But `IDatareader`'s `GetString(n)` method is 0-based, so `GetString(6)` returns the 7th column, which there isn't.

Change it to `GetString(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only seem to need just the last column, you can change your query to:

```
"SELECT [DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE DATA_REGISTRO LIKE @DATA_REGISTRO";
```

And then read it using [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA_REGISTRO", dtParam);
valor.retorna_date_time = objcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

EDIT:

`ExecuteScalar()` [will return a null reference if the query did not return anything.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should check if it is null before converting it to `string` and passing it to `valor.retorna_date_time`. Do something like:

```
string returnValue = objcmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ?? String.Empty : objcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) This error now.

Comment: `objcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` See the edited post.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I don't think that was caused by my answer. You need to revert all your changes before applying any of our suggestions.

Comment: I am making changes in everything according to your changes.

Comment: Okay. My bad. The `ExceuteScalar()` method may be returning a null. First, check if the query works (run it on SSMS). Second, do a null check on the `ExecuteScalar()` method before assigning it to `valor.retorna_date_time`. Refer to this post on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987618/how-to-do-tostring-for-a-possibly-null-object

Comment: Hey I got it. I Change on query LIKE to = and get valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetDateTime(0).ToString() ;

Comment: Ahhh! That `LIKE` was the reason it wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table structure, I would try `GetOrdinal`.

Change

```
valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetString(6)
```

to

```
valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetOrdinal("DATA_REGISTRO");
```

Comment: Its not working too. the table struct is [IDCADASTRO],[RGP] = int,[PEIXE] = varchar,[PESO] = float,[QUANTIDADE] = int,[DATA_REGISTRO] = Date