# C# 6.0 null-coalescing not working correctly for me

Tags: c#

Very simple question, the following code throws a "Nulllable object must have a value" exception.  But I thought that the ?? was going to handle that?

```
  string qty = stop.pallets_qty_total.Value.ToString() ?? "0";
```

Comment: Duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987618/how-to-do-tostring-for-a-possibly-null-object

Comment: No, `x ?? v` is roughly equivalent to `x == null ? v : x`. Do you mean the `?.` operator? In that case you should use `pallets_qty_total?.ToString() ?? "0"`

Comment: Accessing `stop.pallets_qty_total.Value` already throws this exception when `stop.pallets_qty_total` is null - so it does not even reach `??` operator.

Comment: @MikhailLobanov - It's called the [`null conditional operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for `null` on the result that is being returned after calling the `ToString()` method on the `Value` property of `stop.pallets_qty_total` while there is chance that `stop.pallets_qty_total` is `null` and it is also possible that the `stop` itself is `null` which will also cause your code to go in failure.

You need try something like following using **Null-Propogation** operator:

```
string qty = (stop?.pallets_qty_total?.ToString()) ?? "0";
```

Comment: Your right, thank you.  I will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

Although the comments already gives the correct answer, here a more detailed explanation:

Your are right that the `??` operator will take the left operand it its value is not null. Otherwise it will take the right operand. It is essential a short version for:

```
var qty = input == null ? "0" : input;
```

However the exception is not thrown by the assignment. The exception is thrown by the call to `ToString()`.

If your input is `null` your statement equals the following:

```
var qty = ((object)null).ToString();
```

Which obviously throws a `NullReferenceException`.

### Solution:

What you are looking for is the `?.` operator. Which says "call the function if the object is not null". This expands into the following:

```
input != null ? input.ToString() : null
// is equal to
input?.ToString()
```

So the solution for the assignment should be a combination of the two operators:

```
var qty = input?.ToString() ?? "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access [`Value][1]` property of `Nullable<T>` when it does not have the value assigned. As specification says, it will throw and exception:

> If a value of type T has not been assigned to the Nullable object,
>   you can compare it to null and retrieve its HasValue property, **but you
>   cannot access its Value property** or call its other members.

You have two options here - use [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to avoid accessing object properties if object is null:

```
string qty = stop.pallets_qty_total?.Value.ToString() ?? "0";
```

Or you can keep in mind that default value for numeric type is zero. And get default value if nullable does not have value assigned:

```
string qty = stop.pallets_qty_total.GetValueOrDefault().ToString();
```

That will be also tiny [premature performance optimization](https://dzone.com/articles/whats-fastest-null-coalescing-operator-vs-getvalue).

Comment: Knew I should've loaded the answer that got posted when I was writing mine.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an aside to Ehsan Sajjad's answer, you actually don't need the second `?` here, assuming `pallets_qty_total` is an integer.  You can instead use [Nullable.GetValueOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
 string qty = stop?.pallets_qty_total.GetValueOrDefault().ToString();
```

If `pallets_qty_total` has a value, it will return it.  If not, it will return `default(T)`, which, in the case of an `int`, is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It will only check if the Value is null but if object before is null then it well throw exception.

```
string qty = stop?.pallets_qty_total?.Value.ToString() ?? "0";
```