# Why c# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((DataTime?)null).ToString()) do not throw Exception?

Tags: c#, .net

why c# code

```
            DateTime? temp = null;
            Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp.ToString()));
```

just print out "True" and do not throw null object Exception?

have run this code in Debug and Release build both do not throw exception
using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: That’s a nullable struct. Not a reference type

Answer (score 3):

Nullable is a struct. You can call methods on empty structs just fine, and `ToString` for an empty nullable returns `string.Empty`. No magic involved :)

The only real magic with nullables has to do with boxing. When you box, say, an integer, you get a boxed integer (`(object)10` returns an `object` which can be cast to `int` - and actually *only* `int`). But when you box a *nullable* integer without a value, you actually get `null`, not a boxed nullable integer (while a nullable integer *with* value will turn into a perfectly normal `int` when boxed, *not* `int?`). So:

```
DateTime? temp = null;
var boxedTemp = (object)temp;
Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(boxedTemp.ToString()));
```

*will* actually throw, because boxedTemp *is* a null reference (while temp is *not a reference in the first place*, so it can't be a *null* reference specifically).

Answer (score 1):

Because the Nullable<DateTime> returns an empty string if its HasValue property is "false".

Here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2