# Identifying null objects in C#

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a method call which takes the results of another four method calls as parameters--but the methods making those calls may or may not be null (sorry if that's a hopelessly unintelligible sentence).  Here's the code, if it makes things clearer:

```
    public void Inform(Room north, Room south, Room east, Room west)
    {
        this.north = north;
        this.south = south;
        this.east = east;
        this.west = west;

        node.Inform(north.GetNode(), south.GetNode(),
                    east.GetNode(), west.GetNode());
    }
```

Basically, I want to know if there's a quick and easy way to check if an object is null and simply pass 'null' into the method besides conditionals--I'd rather not have to explicitly code for all 16 possible variations of null/not null.

EDIT: In response to confusion, I want to clarify this: most of the time the objects I'm passing into the method won't be null.  Usually, `Room` objects exist for north, south, east, and west, and if the `Room` exists, the GetNode() method will return the appropriate object.  I want to determine if a given `Room` exists to avoid null reference excpetions upon trying to make a method call.

Comment: Your question is confusing. If an object is `null`, and you want to pass `null`... why not just pass the object? The `null` value will pass through. Perhaps you could post a short sample of the sixteen-variation code you envision, so we can see exactly what results you want?

Comment: I know this is a dupe of another SO question but I can't find it. but what I think you want is something like this: `node.Inform(north == null ? null : north.GetNode(), ...);`

Comment: ok, so not an exact dupe but similar enough to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550374/checking-for-null-before-tostring

Comment: Domenic, most of the time the object won't be null--I expect to have some object which returned to be passed into the method.  However, because the object making the call which returns the object I want (i.e. north making a call to GetNode()) may be null, throwing an exception, I want to be able to determine if the Room objects are null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public void Inform(Room north, Room south, Room east, Room west)
    {
        this.north = north;
        this.south = south;
        this.east = east;
        this.west = west;

        node.Inform(GetNode(north), GetNode(south),
                    GetNode(east),GetNode(west));
    } 

    private Node GetNode(Room room)
    {
        return room == null ?  null : room.GetNode();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

```
static Node GetNodeOrNull(this Room room)
{
  return room == null ? null : room.GetNode();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the rest of your code (which I have to :)) - you could start using the Null Pattern.  Eg have a NullRoom class and have its GetNode() return something meaningfull. Basically never allow an actual null reference.