# convert Null Value from convert.tostring()

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have code like this.

```
string b=null;
string a = Convert.ToString(b);
```

Ref from:

[Checking for null before ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550374/checking-for-null-before-tostring)

But while i convert b to string i get only null value not empty string.but some days ago i have also done null coversion using same convert.tostring(). at that it works fine but now not working. i am rotating my head here and there pls help me why this is happening? only thing is that i worked in 3.5 framework but now 4.0 .

Answer (score 5):

Convert.ToString(string) will return the string unchanged. This is true of every version of the framework, as per the documentation:

- [4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You are mistaken that calling `Convert.ToString((string)null)` ever returned anything except null. What you were **probably** calling was `Convert.ToString((object)null)`. This [will return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh) empty-string.

```
string a = Convert.ToString((object)null);
string b = Convert.ToString((string)null);
// a now equals string.Empty, but b equals null.
```

You could cast string `b` to an object as I have done, but I would suggest you use the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator instead:

```
string a = b ?? string.Empty
```

Comment: yes i understand we need to pass null value as object datatype not string datatype . you r also right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

string a = (b == null) ? string.Empty : b;

Comment: which is equivalent to `string a = b ?? string.Empty`

Answer (score 0):

When we are doing any Conversion's try to check whether it is null or not.

Try to do like this

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
{
string c=Convert.ToString(b);
}
```